# Can "just" and "already" be used with past tense and with a specific time?

Tags: adverbs, time

Can "just" and "already" be used with past tense and with a specific time?

**Example 1**

> I just met her five hours ago.

**Example 2**

> I already told her about the party five hours ago.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, both of those sentences are correct and natural.

The general rule is that you cannot have more than one *time expression* referring to the same verb, so these are incorrect:

> <del>**Earlier**, I met her **five hours ago**.</del>
> <del>**Before I left home**, I told her about the party **five hours ago**.</del>

"Just" and "already" aren't time expressions, so it's OK to have them in a sentence with a time expression like "five hours ago".